# EF ModelValidationException Each property name in a type must be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

In entity framework I am trying to configure a **0 to Many** relationships based on this [tutorial](https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-for-beginners-code-first-model-using-fluentapi/). Here Student can have **0 or many** contacts. But the code shows below exception in runtime.

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException
>
> StudentId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property
> name 'StudentId' is already defined.

```
public class Student 
{
    public Student()
    {
        Contacts = new EntityHashSet<Contact>();
    }        
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEntityHashSet<Contact> Contacts { get; private set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
    public int ContactId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; protected set; }
}


public static void Configure(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{          
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Contacts)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Student)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.StudentId);
}
```

I have tried removing HasForeignKey also. But nothing works.

Comment: The bad thing is that the tutorial does not reflect the sample code at all :-)

Comment: remove `.WithRequired(e => e.Student).HasForeignKey(e => e.StudentId);` from the `Student` model builder - `Student` does not have a foreign key to itself usually - EF tries to add you that foreign key as property, but you already have it as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the key for Student

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(x => x.StudentId);
```

Comment: I have tried this one and also tried with adding [Key] attribute in my entity. Didn't work

Comment: Try removing the StudentId from Contact, the ef do not njeed it and will autogenerate it in database and you can test wich is the StudientId property that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think the appropriate relationship is one to many where one student can have many contacts (from 0 to many).

I have done a relationship this way:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Contacts = new HashSet<Contacts>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact 
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; } //usually I use Annotations here to create the DB like.. [Column("column_name")]
    //Here I use [InverseProperty(Contact), ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public static void Configure(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contacts>.HasOne(a => a.Student).WithMany(b => b.Contacts).HasForeignKey(a => a.StudentId);    
}
```

It should work without the annotations.